# In Docker, is it a good practice to compose complex stacks from separate compose files?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-stack

We are moving some of our internal services to rely on Docker instead of direct installation on the host OS (good thing, right :).

We use `docker stack` command with compose file (as it felt to us it is the modern approach). But we are not sure about how to properly make our stacks modular, while allowing composition:

---

Let's imagine we have two stacks: `stackA` and `stackB`. Those two can perfectly be used in isolation, so for the moment we decided to host them in two separate repositories, each containing the `docker-compose.yml` of the corresponding stack.

Yet, there is also a mode where `stackB` can communicate with `stackA` to provide additional features. On some nodes, we might want to deploy both, and have them communicate.

By default, when we start both stacks on the same node with:

```
docker stack deploy -c stackA/ A-stack
docker stack deploy -c stackB/ B-stack
```

Both end up on different overlay networks, and cannot easily communicate.

It seems we are faced with a choice, for which we could only find 3 options at the moment:

- We have seen ways to add external networks to `stackB` in its compose file, but that means now the `stackB` can only be deployed if `stackA` already runs (because it wants to join an external network)
- We could define another compose file, manually merging both. But that leads us to maintain another repo, and duplicate changes.
- We could have the stack communicate over the host network through exposed ports, but it might feel a bit weird.

---

Is there a best/recommended approach to keep different stacks modular, while allowing to easily compose them?

Or is it an implicit assumption that as soon as two containers are supposed to communicate, they have to be deployed from the same compose file?

Comment: I run into some network issues with multiple stacks maybe it's also interesting for your final decision https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968697/reload-docker-stack-network-configuration

Answer (score 1):

I handle usually handle more than one stack in cases when I want handle them separate. Common situations are horizontal scaling of same web service image for different customer installations with different configurations f.e. databases.

The separated stacks allow me easy to shutdown them without any impact of other installations

I also like the standard naming conventions in multiple stack installations. Same services have same names beside the stack prefix.

To let the stack communicate over the boundaries thy only have to share the same network.

The first stack defines in my cases implizit a network and the other stack join that network by compose file configuration.

```
...
networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: FIRST_STACK_NAME_default
...
```