# Reload docker stack network configuration

Tags: docker, networking, docker-swarm

I have multiple docker stacks that are connected over the same network. If I restart one of the stacks the internal ip addresses of the related stack container seems to change. That results in wrong service name resolutions in other stacks and containers. It seems that the internal docker name service doesn't recognize the network change.

If try to access other containers with ping from a stack container shell by the service name (for example `ping my_stack_my_container_name`) I got a successful return from a wrong IP address. When I use the full container name instead (`ping my_stack_my_container_name.134.134234234123`) the return comes from the right IP.

Is there any way to trigger a reload of the stack networking/name service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure it's not reloaded? check if the docker containers (that should connect to reloaded container) are not caching DNS query results. I had same issue in haproxy config and I placed following lines to force haproxy to hold values only for 1s:

```
resolvers docker
    # well known docker dns server address
    nameserver dns 127.0.0.11:53
    #HAProxy will hold name-ip mapping for 1s, so for each request new container ip will be resolved, balancing load
    hold valid 1s
```

(...)

```
backend stackName_app_backend
    server stackName_app_service stackName_ServiceName:80 resolvers docker check
```

Comment: It's the case in containers from different images alpine and debian - i am going to check the container caches

Comment: And it's the same situation in the new started container. I opened a shell and do a ping to the service name and got the response from a different address (same network but different address then in ifconfing)

Comment: That's correct, because the docker service name is resolved by DNS to the VIP of the service for load balancing purposes. You can configure your service to be blanaced by DNS Round Robin - then the inner dns server (127.0.0.11) will respond with direct container addresses in a RR way.